# How to convert a stream to PdfDocument in PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

Everywhere I get examples of creating `PdfDocument` like this:

`PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(fiePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);`

But I don't have the path of file. I want to convert `Stream` to `PdfDocument`. I tried this:

`PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(stream);`

but it always gives `0` as `PageCount` and `PageSize`.

Comment: I've never used PDFsharp but, as far as I can tell, you just call `PdfReader.Open` and pass a `Stream` instead of a `String`. The overloads that take a file path actually create a `FileStream` and then call the overloads that take a `Stream`. Source code [here](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/4577/NClass/lib/PdfSharp/PdfSharp/PdfSharp.Pdf.IO/PdfReader.cs/).

Comment: @jmcilhinney Your answer is spot-on, but posted as a comment. I'll delete my answer if you create an answer yourself.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PdfReader.Open` can be invoked with a filename or with a stream.

What you tried (`new PdfDocument(stream)`) creates a new and empty document that can be written to the stream by invoking `Save()` without parameter. This creates a document, but does not open it.